# WPF get selected Combobox value which is bound to observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, class, combobox, observablecollection

I have a `ComboBox` (CBaddress) which is bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

XAML

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name="CBaddress"
   Height="23"
   Margin="80,75,423,0"
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddressTemplate}"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}"
/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AddressTemplate">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=ID_}" />
      <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Address_}" />
      <TextBlock Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=HouseNumber_}" />
      <TextBlock Width="40" Text="{Binding Path=PostalCode_}" />
      <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=State_}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ObservableCollection` consists of a `class` (Address).

```
class Address
{
   public int ID_ { get; set; }
   public string Country_ { get; set; }
   public string State_ { get; set; }
   public int PostalCode_ { get; set; }
   public string Address_ { get; set; }
   public int HouseNumber_ { get; set; }
}
```

When my program starts it loads all values from a database and can display all values perfectly in the `ComboBox`:

```
CBaddress.DataContext = database.SelectAllAddresses();
```

But how do I get the values? With `CBaddress.Text` I get only this output :

> MySQL_WPF.classes.Address

Is it possible to get the plain text, which is also displayed in the `ComboBox`?

It would be best if I could get a certain value from the selected value, like the `ID_`.

Comment: Which property should be displayed in the `ComboBox`? What do you meant by "how do I get the values?"? Which values do you want to get, the selected item, all items?

Comment: the properties that are displayed in the XAML DataTemplate and thats all right. My question was, how I can work with the selected value. Like is it possible to get only the ID_ of the selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the selected item, access it with the `SelectedItem` property on `ComboBox`.

```
var selectedID = ((Address)CBaddress.SelectedItem).ID_ ;
```

The `SelectedItem` property is of type `object`, so you need to cast it to your data type `Address`. Then you can access any of its properties as usual.

If you are working in an MVVM scenario, you would bind the `SelectedItem` to a property on your view model, e.g. `SelectedAddress`.

```
<ComboBox ...
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectedItem={Binding SelectedAddress}"/>
```

```
private Address _selectedAddress;
public Address SelectedAddress
{
   get => _selectedAddress;
   set
   {
      if (_selectedAddress == value)
         return;

      _selectedAddress = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Then you could access any property the same way, e.g.:

```
var selectedID = SelectedAddress.ID_;
```